# Forget which client certificate is used by Chrome for an URL

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, client-certificates

I'm using a client certificate to authenticate with HTTPS to a website. 
The first time, chrome asked me which certificate I wanted to use.
However, I don't how to flush/forget this choice to choose another certificate. Chrome remembers it and I didn't find (either in stackoverflow or chrome settings) a solution to that.

The only way I found is to open a new window in private mode.

Anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: It seems like restart chrome is working, but it is not a very practical way do it...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Restarting the browser will help and ask you again.
Looking forward to see better solutions.

Comment: This is not a solution.

Comment: This worked for me, clearing cache didn't solve it, i had to restart chrome too.

Comment: @CochiseRuhulessin this is literally the only solution without going incognito

Comment: @JohnRed you have to COMPLETELY close your browser. if you have it set to run in the background you need to kill the process

Comment: It does not work anymore, nothing works, not clearing cache, not closing chrome, not incognito.

Comment: Restarting worked!, There can be another way to clear the set certificate in mid browser session. But Restarting the chrome definitely works!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If restarting didn't work, it may because there is still Chrome process is running, just kill the process manually, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

Open the target URL in an incognito session, and it should re-prompt. Not a great solution, but to me it beats having to restart all of Chrome, especially if you already had a lot of important tabs open.

Comment: It does not work anymore, nothing works, not clearing cache, not closing chrome, not incognito.

Comment: Trying closing all Incognito windows first.

Answer (score 5):

This particular thing has sucked since the beginning of web browsers. The only solution is to use the platform [APIs](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/certificate-management-extension-api-on-chrome-os) to build extension to manage client certificates. This is in fact what Google recommends but it's mainly for CAs and other solution providers. So the only way is to reload the browser or use incognito windows.

Comment: It does not work anymore, nothing works, not clearing cache, not closing chrome, not incognito.

Answer (score 2):

It's 2023 and I faced the same problem...

What worked for me is to also clear **Site Settings**.

Answer (score 0):

There's now a new "Your certificate choices" option in Microsoft Edge:

[image]